# How to get the object from a dictionary for a key that is an NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key, nsdictionary, nsobject

Likely there already are posts dealing with this issue, but I'm not able to find exactly what I want... I've an `NSMutableDictionary` whose keys are a subclass of `NSObject<NSCopying>`. I'm finding that `objectForKey:` is not working, I'm getting always `nil` even if I use the same key object I've just used for calling `setObject:forKey:`.

What the best way to handle this should be?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setObject:forKey:` the key is copied, so the dictionary doesn't get the key object itself. That's why you are getting nil when you call `objectForKey:`.

You need to implement also `-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you need implement

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone;
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
- (NSUInteger)hash;
```

all method all above in order to use NSObject as key in NSDictionary